# What did River say when she woke from her proto-comatose state?

Tags: firefly

In Firefly Episode 9,  *Ariel*, River and Simon take a drug that puts them in a proto-comatose state.

Around 17:30, River wakes up, says *something*, and startles Jayne. Jayne responds "What did you say?" but never gets an answer.

**What did she say?**

The subtitles I have just say "[Mutters]". But I assume that Summer Glau chose some words to say, even if they didn't form a logical sentence.

I've listened over and over, and my best guess is "Copper for a King". But I could be way off.

[image]

Comment: What does "proto-comatose" mean? Is that a real word, or is it something from that show?

Comment: @user14111 - It's a quote from episode 8 - River says (to Simon) "*You're going to suspend cerebral, cardiac and pulmonary activity... in order to induce a proto-comatose state.*"

Comment: @Valorum Well, is it a real word, or some gobbledegook they made up for the show? I'm guessing the latter. I don't find it in the online OED, but of course they keep adding new words all the time, so maybe they just haven't got to it yet.

Comment: @User14111 - It's entirely made up. You can't be *proto-* comatose any more than you can be para-pregant or semi-dead.

Comment: @Valorum Yet you can be MOSTLY dead. Mostly dead is still slightly alive. If someone was all dead, there's only one thing you can do.

Comment: +1 just for being dang close with your analysis.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The [official shooting script](http://www.myths.com/pub/tv/firefly/script-ariel.html) has the line;

> [Behind Jayne (and unseen by him) River SITS UP INTO FRAME. She's just woken up and is a bit dazed, disoriented. She's inches behind him as she says --]
>
> **RIVER:** *A copper for a kiss.*
>
> [Jayne jumps -- she startled the hell out of him.]

Comment: As scary as she is? That'd startle me, too!